# Как добавить html блок в админ панель битрикс

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Есть инфоблок "Главная страница", хочу при редактировании элемента инфоблока, добавить ссылку, по которой бы пользователь переходил в нужный инфоблок, где мог бы редактировать что-нибудь. Но не совсем понимаю как это можно реализовать (простым способом), не делая собственное свойство для этой цели.